# `TransitiveClosureGraph` doesn't return self-loops for nodes that are in a cycle

Tags: graphs-and-networks

This is from [boost library documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/transitive_closure.html):

> The transitive closure of a graph G = (V,E) is a graph G* = (V,E*)
>   such that E* contains an edge (u,v) if and only if G contains a path
>   (of at least one edge) from u to v.

For example from C++ Boost library (left: the input graph) (right: the transitive closure of the input graph):

[image] [image]

Using mathematica for the same graph ignores the self-loops :

[image]

I kinda fixed it by finding cycles and adding loops:

```
loopyTransitiveClosure[g_] :=
 (candidate = TransitiveClosureGraph[g];
  cycles = Flatten@FindCycle[g];
  Do[If[MemberQ[cycles, i \[DirectedEdge] _], 
    candidate = EdgeAdd[candidate, i \[DirectedEdge] i]],{i,VertexList[G]}];
  candidate)
```

And it works fine:

[image]

But I bet this is so inefficient. How can I implement it from scratch to work efficient and handle the loopy cases ? Especially I need to get `O(|V||E|)` complexity that [Boost Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/transitive_closure.html) provides.

Comment: The `boost` definition is correct.  Why is Mma's behavior not a bug?

Comment: As further evidence that TransitiveClosureGraph should be considered buggy, note that even if the original graph includes self loops, these will be omitted by its purported transitive closure!

Comment: This persists in 11.1.  Shouldn't it get the `bug` tag?

Answer (score 2):

`Combinatorica` does that out of the box:

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
Needs["GraphUtilities`"]
list = DirectedEdge @@@ {{d, a}, {d, c}, {c, b}, {b, c}, {b, d}};
g = System`Graph@list
gComb = ToCombinatoricaGraph@g;
ShowGraph[gCT = Combinatorica`TransitiveClosure@gComb]
myG = System`Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ ToOrderedPairs@gCT]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics] 
[image: Mathematica graphics]

The usual caveats when using `Combinatorica` apply.